# Obj-C/iOS: How to retrieve contents of NSData and interact?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, nsdata

I'm retrieving a unix timestamp from a Bluetooth LE peripheral, which is stored in an NSData object. If I print the contents of the NSData object to the debug console, they appear correct, however if I try to convert the NSData object to an integer value, the integer value appears to keep changing.

`NSData *refinedData = [mfrData subdataWithRange:range];`

Which yields a value of 386d5e9a on the debug console.

I then convert to an integer:

`uint32_t unixTimeStamp = refinedData;`

Initially, this yields a value of 342162144 on the debug console. However, this value keeps growing, despite the NSData not changing. Can anybody help me understand what's going on?

If it's not already very apparent, I'm a newbie.

Thanks.

Comment: 386d5e9a seems like a memory address to me. Have you tried converting the data to a CString and printing that, it might shed some light on the issue. How are you producing that value in the debug console? using NSLog?

Comment: I am getting it by using NSLog, however, I'm certain it's the value that I'm after, b/c I have hard coded it (for testing purposes) on the device.

Comment: I see you got the answer anyway. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refinedData` is a pointer to an instance of NSData. You want to access its contents:

```
uint32_t unixTimeStamp = *(uint32_t *)[refinedData bytes];
```

Note that this is simplified, and assumes that the bytes returned by the Bluetooth peripheral are the same endianness as the processor in your device, that `range` is correct, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. This may be a stupidly basic question, but in the image below, is 16e5b718 the memory address and 386d5e9a the contents or is it the other way around?http://www.flickr.com/photos/chrisdurst/10060253855/
If I use Andrew's method, then unixTimeStamp = 16e5b718.

Comment: Doh! My answer had a mistake. You need to dereference the bytes pointer, after casting it to a pointer to a `uint32_t`. I've fixed the code. With the previous (incorrect) code, unixTimeStamp would be the address in memory of the first byte of refinedData's contents. You want the bytes contained by refinedData themselves, so you need to dereference that pointer (address). Try again with my updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, that worked. All I had to do was swap the endian-ness and it worked like a treat. I owe you a beer. Thanks.